# FindMoleculeSubstructure fails on SMARTS MoleculePattern, but MoleculePlot is OK?

Tags: pattern-matching, chemistry

*Background Info*: [SMARTS is a convention for specifying molecular patterns](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html).  It is supported by Mathematica 12's [MoleculePattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculePattern.html) function.

*Problem Setup*:  Consider
`MoleculePattern["[!#6;!#1;!H0]"]]`
This means "match atoms that are not carbon and not hydrogen and have more than zero hydrogens attached."

*What seems to work OK:* The `Molecule["CNO"]` has two atoms satisfying that pattern, and indeed, [MoleculePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculePlot.html) *correctly* highlights both the nitrogen and oxygen atoms:

```
MoleculePlot[
 Molecule["CNO"],
 MoleculePattern["[!#6;!#1;!H0]"]]
```

[image: molecule image showing O and N highlighted]

*What seems to be a problem:* [FindMoleculeSubstructure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMoleculeSubstructure.html) does not find both atoms; it *incorrectly* only finds the nitrogen (atom 2) but not the oxygen:

```
FindMoleculeSubstructure[
 Molecule["CNO"],
 MoleculePattern["[!#6;!#1;!H0]"]]
```

> {<|1 -> 2|>}

(the returned association means "pattern 1 matched by atom 2 in the molecule)

*Updated:*  I think this is an error with the arguments/documentation for [FindMoleculeSubstructure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMoleculeSubstructure.html). The documentation says that providing no third argument searches for *all* matches, but if I add the third argument, then I find the correct number of matches.  For example:

```
FindMoleculeSubstructure[
 Molecule["CNO"],
 MoleculePattern["[!#6;!#1;!H0]"],
 10]
```

> {<|1 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 3|>}

(which is correct)

*Gratuitous additional examples*:  This appears to occurs with other MoleculePattern types.  The exact same type of problem (two matches correctly found with MoleculePlot, but only one found with FindMoleculeSubstructure) also occurs with `MoleculePattern["[C;H3,H4]"]]` for `Molecule["CCC"]`, as well as the same "fix".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FindMoleculeSubstructure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMoleculeSubstructure.html) is modeled after [`FindGraphIsomorphism`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGraphIsomorphism.html), and by default returns only a single match.  The third argument controls how many mappings are returned.

```
In[14]:= FindMoleculeSubstructure[
    Molecule @ "CNO", 
    MoleculePattern @ "[!#6;!#1;!H0]", 
    All
]

Out[14]= {<|1 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 3|>}
```

`n` has to have a default value, it can't be $\infty$ because you can easily ask for matches on a very general pattern and get way too many back.

```
In[12]:= Length@
 FindMoleculeSubstructure[
  Molecule[Entity["Chemical", "FullereneC60"]], 
  MoleculePattern["*.*.*"], All]

Out[12]= 34220
```

Comment: Makes total sense.  Perhaps there is an opportunity to clarify the documentation?  ```?FindMoleculeSubstructure```  says that "FindMoleculeSubstructure[mol,patt] finds a mapping between the atom indices in mol and *all* occurrences of patt in mol."

Comment: I will change the wording on the usage messages, you are right.